# DNN skin background position being ignored

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, skinning

I'm working on a DNN skin and I need to set a background image set at bottom position.

- I've tried setting background-position within skin.css and with the
  custom stylesheet tool in admin panel. But when inspecting this css
  property in FireFox or Safari, its being ignored... (strike through
  text).
- I've also tried using .body, #body and Body style... but can't
  get it to work.
- And finally I tried using a div as wrapper containing header,
  contents and footer; that seems to work but that leads me to another problem: the overflowed content wont show and the browser wont show the scrollbar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it shown as struck through when inspecting then that means it is being overwritten by something else and you should be able to determine what is overriding it by looking in the inspector. Often in cases like this you'll need a more specific combination of classes/objects in your CSS to prevent overriding. Or, you could just append !important for the style.

Comment: problem was i was using min-height:100%, i changed that to simple height:100%
thank you